# Which kind of trees can be represented by XML

Tags: xml, graph, tree

I just started to learn for an advanced database course. And I have one basic question, a standart tree is a [connected acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory). The connected refers to that all nodes are connected somehow and acyclic mean no cycles. My question is what other graphs can be represented by an XML file that respects the [xml standart](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/)?

Maybe [directed acyclic graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), but for each node I can verfiy if a parent is available, so directed seems to be strange. And cycles, I really don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as I know you always have to have a unique root tag in an XML document, so that would already give you an '**rooted** connected acyclic graph' (rooted tree). Furthermore, you can interpret the names of nodes in an XML document as labels on nodes in your graph. The individual properties could be expressed by functions on the nodes or, if that's more desirable, as labels/predicates.

By definition your XML document always has a tree structure, so the underlying graphs will always be trees.

Comment: Yes, your right but, does it mean that these trees may not have cycles and also can't be directed?

Comment: Well by definition a tree cannot have a cycle. Since an XML node contains several other nodes you might think of that as being directed.